# Error en capturar la variable al llamar a un Sweet Alert - PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, sweetalert

estoy haciendo un crud de una tabla con un foreach para mostrar los datos de la base de datos, la tabla vendría a ser la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy haciendo las confirmaciones de eliminación con un SweetAlert, que al dar a confirmar, la fila se elimina. El problema vendría a ser que cuando quiero capturar el valor del `<?php echo $row['incidencia_nombres'] ?>` en mi SweetAlert, me tendría que mostrar el nombre de la fila que yo estoy deseando eliminar, pero me está mostrando el último dato.

Aquí quise eliminar la fila 3, de la cual me tendría que mostrar el nombre "Daniel" y no a "Hector", siendo el último nombre de la columna.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error también me sucedería al redireccionar el `href`, ya que quiero capturar el `id` de la fila que deseo eliminar y enviarlo a mi archivo php para que proceda a eliminar mediante ese `id` que va a recoger, pero eliminaría la última fila.

Adjunto el código del `<tbody>` de mi tabla tabla, donde muestro los datos y llamo al Sweet Alert a través de una función javascript.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">#</th>
            <th class="text-center">Acción</th>
            <th class="text-center">Nombres</th>
            <th class="text-center">Apellidos</th>
            <th class="text-center">DNI</th>
            <th class="text-center">Teléfono</th>
            <th class="text-center">Dirección</th>
            <th class="text-center">Medicina</th>
            <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $i++?></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <a target="_blank" href="editincidencia.php?id=<?php echo $row['incidencia_id'] ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>
                <a target="_blank" href="invoiceprintIncidencias.php?id=<?php echo $row['incidencia_id'] ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button></a>
                <a onclick="removeIncidencias()"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
            </td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_nombres'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_apellidos'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_dni'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_telefono'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_direccion'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_nombre_medicina'] ?></td>
            <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_fecha'] ?></td>
        </tr>
        <script>
            function removeIncidencias() {
            Swal.fire({
                title: '¿Eliminar incidencia?',
                text: "Procederás a eliminar a <?php echo $row['incidencia_nombres'] ?>, recuerda que... ¡Esto es irreversible!", //El error ocurriría aquí
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                confirmButtonText: '¡Sí, eliminar!',
                cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
            }).then((result) => {
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                    Swal.fire(
                        '¡Eliminado!',
                        'Incidencia eliminada correctamente.',
                        'success'
                    )
                    window.location.href = "php_action/removeIncidencias.php?id=<?php echo $row['incidencia_id']?>"; //El error ocurriría aquí también
                }
            });
        };
        </script>
    </tbody>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
```

El Sweet Alert lo estoy poniendo dentro del foreach para que supuestamente capture el valor de la fila que yo desee eliminar, pero está cogiendo siempre el último, agradecería muchísimo su ayuda.

Comment: En la funcion removeIncidencias le debes pasar el nombre que quieres mostrar, ya que como tal, esta tomando todo los nombres, le deberias pasar solo 1 nombre por cada row y despues mostrarlo

Comment: Tiene sentido, ¿Me podrías explicar más detalladamente con el código?, te lo agradecería.

Comment: La respuesta de Fernando te puede ayudar, si observas el boton, cuando hace onClick, en la funcion pasa varios parametros, tu puedes pasar los que ocupes, onclick="removeIncidencias(usuarioAborrar)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo en tu código estas definiendo en cada iteración la función **removeIncidencias()**

al terminar las iteraciones de tu foreach el ultimo registro es el de **Hector**
por lo que independientemente de cual registro selecciones la función esta definida para que muestre y elimine esté registro.

te recomiendo hacer más uso de JavaScript, la solución a tu problema es el siguiente

```
<?php   
foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $i++?></td>
      <td class="text-center">
         <a target="_blank" href="editincidencia.php?id=<?php echo $row['incidencia_id'] ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="invoiceprintIncidencias.php?id=<?php echo $row['incidencia_id'] ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-print"></i></button></a>
            <a onclick="removeIncidencias(<?php echo $row['incidencia_id'] ?>, '<?php echo $row['incidencia_nombres'] ?>")'><button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></a>
        </td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_nombres'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_apellidos'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_dni'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_telefono'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_direccion'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_nombre_medicina'] ?></td>
        <td style="color: black;" class="text-center"><?php echo $row['incidencia_fecha'] ?></td>
    </tr>
?>
```

a la etiqueta A donde haces el onClick a la función *removeIncidencias()* le agregué dos parámetros, que son el id de la incidencia y el nombre que quieres mostrar

una vez que terminas el foreach y fuera de el para que solo se defina una sola vez pondremos tu función

```
<script>
        function removeIncidencias(idIncidencia,nombreMostrar) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: '¿Eliminar incidencia?',
            text: "Procederás a eliminar a "+nombreMostrar+", recuerda que... ¡Esto es irreversible!", //El error ocurriría aquí
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: '¡Sí, eliminar!',
            cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                Swal.fire(
                    '¡Eliminado!',
                    'Incidencia eliminada correctamente.',
                    'success'
                )
                window.location.href = "php_action/removeIncidencias.php?id="+idIncidencia; //El error ocurriría aquí también
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

el cambio que realicé en tu función fue agregar los dos parámetros que recibirá una vez que hagas click sobre la etiqueta A, posteriormente en vez de imprimir los datos con php se concatena el parámetro nombreMostrar al string que donde le preguntas al usuario si desea eliminar la incidencia, y en caso de confirmar se concatena el parámetro idIncidencia al string donde cambias de url

como te comentaba te recomiendo que estudies y que hagas más uso de javascript ya que esta forma de resolver este problema no es la mejor, solo es una manera fácil y sin que tengas que modificar mucho tu código

Comment: ¡Genial!, pero hay una observación, en el `onclick() ` faltó agregar comillas simples a las variables del php para enviarlos como un string al modal, es por eso que me salía error luego de aplicar lo que me indicaste. De todas formas te agradezco bastante por ayudarme en mi problema, saludos.